# check python version(s) from within a python script and if/else based on that

Tags: python, unicode

Basically I'd like to know if there is a way to know what version of python a script is using from within the script?  Here's my current example of where I'd like to use it:

I would like to make a python script use unicode if it is using python 2, but otherwise not use unicode.  I currently have python 2.7.5 and python 3.4.0 installed, and am running my current project under python 3.4.0. The following scirpt:

```
_base = os.path.supports_unicode_filenames and unicode or str
```

was returning the error:

```
    _base = os.path.supports_unicode_filenames and unicode or str
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

So I changed it to this in order to get it to work:

```
_base = os.path.supports_unicode_filenames and str
```

Is there a way to change it to something to this effect:

```
if python.version == 2:

    _base = os.path.supports_unicode_filenames and unicode or str

else:

    _base = os.path.supports_unicode_filenames and str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define `unicode` for Python 3:

```
try:
    unicode = unicode
except NameError: # Python 3 (or no unicode support)
    unicode = str # str type is a Unicode string in Python 3
```

To check version, you could use `sys.version`, `sys.hexversion`, `sys.version_info`:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
   print('before Python 3 (Python 2)')
else: # Python 3
   print('Python 3 or newer')
```

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer since it hit the nail on the head, for handling the "can't find 'unicode' error" and how to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

You are very close:

```
import sys
sys.version_info
```

Would return:

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

and you can do something like this:

```
import sys
ver = sys.version_info[0]
if ver == 2:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sys.version_info` to check your Python version. For example:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    ... stuff
else:
    ... stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look into the [`six`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) library to better support the differences between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Roseman. That library looks super useful. I'm gonna have to start using more, and then definitely it would work in this case.